# Unable to use signal handling

Tags: c++, macos, signals

I have been trying to experiment with signals in C++ and didn't have much luck so far.

I am working on a MacBook Pro M2, 2022 with XCode 14.3.1 and I have tried to replicate the example from the `std::signal` cppreference page (link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal) shown below

```cpp
#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>
 
namespace {
    volatile std::sig_atomic_t gSignalStatus;
}
 
void signal_handler(int signal) {
    gSignalStatus = signal;
}
 
int main() {
    // Install a signal handler
    std::signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
 
    std::cout << "SignalValue: " << gSignalStatus << '\n';
    std::cout << "Sending signal: " << SIGINT << '\n';
    std::raise(SIGINT);
    std::cout << "SignalValue: " << gSignalStatus << '\n';
}
```

The result should be

```
SignalValue: 0
Sending signal: 2
SignalValue: 2
```

which is verified both on cppreference page (running the example) as well as "Compiler Explorer" with x86-64 clang 16.0.0, x86-64 clang 15.0.0 and x86-64 clang 14.0.0, x86-64 clang (trunk), x86-64 gcc (trunk), x86-64 gcc 13.2 and x86-64 gcc 12.3 (just to make sure it is working "in general").

The exact same code gives the following results in the configuration I have

```
SignalValue: 0
Sending signal: 2
SignalValue: 0
```

It seems that the `signal_handler` function is never called and the behaviour is the same in *Debug* (`-O0`) and *Release* (`-O3` and `-Os`). I have absolutely no idea why this is happening, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you are invoking your program with SIGINT blocked, such as from some IDEs?  The code works for me on a similar compilation environment when executed from an ordinary interactive shell.

Comment: Thanks @pilcrow, I didn't know that some IDEs block some signals. I'll try executing from the terminal and see what results I get. I'll update you accordingly.

Comment: @pilcrow running from the terminal seems to fix the problem, so it seems that XCode is indeed blocking the signals, or at least this one. Could you please write that as an answer to accept it and be here for future reference so others can benefit from it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are invoking the test program under an IDE that is blocking SIGINT, and the signal mask is inherited by its children (copied over a `fork()` of course, and then [preserved across an `execve()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html)).

Try invoking the executable from a plain interactive shell, and you should see the expected behavior.  Alternately, try SIGUSR1, which is rarely blocked by things like IDEs.